# Getting CORS policy error for function in same Firebase project

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase project and it has functions. I created a function weeks ago and am calling it just fine. I created a new function and call it exactly like I call the first one, and i'm gett this in the browser:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://xxxxxxxx/listProjects' from origin 'https://yyyy.web.app' 
has been blocked by CORS policy
```

This is the backend function:

```
   exports.listProjects = functions.https.onCall(async (
      data, context) => {
          return {
           text: 'OK'
        };
     });
```

As you can see, i'm not doing anything. Here is how I call it on the frontend:

```
   let send = this.$functions.httpsCallable("listProjects");
      send({ data: data }).then((result) => {
           console.log("projects", result.data.text);
  });
```

Here's a screenshot of the two functions in firebase:

[image]

How do i unblock my new function so I no longer get the CORS error?

Comment: Thats the point. What am I mssing? I dont see anything wrong either

Answer (score 1):

CORS stands for "Cross Origin Resource Sharing". Because different websites getting files from each other is dangerous, it is blocked by default.

To unblock it, you must set some request headers, namely `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *`. This allows different sites to share resources to the site you are posting this on.

So unless you have access to modify the headers, you can't unblock this.

On Firebase, you can modify `firebase.json` so it looks like this:

```json
"hosting": {
  "headers": [ {
    "source": "*",
    "headers": [ {
      "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "value": "*"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Comment: How do I do that? And why am I not getting a CORS error when I call the other function from the same website the exact same way?

Comment: I have another project with TONS of functions. Never had a CORS problem.  I copied that project for my new one. Firebase can handle multiple functions.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Someone_who_likes_SE said, it seems obvious that the issue lies in the implementation of the function you're receiving the error from.

To prevent this kind of CORS policy errors, your code should be able to handle CORS requests. For instance, and following the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http), you can see a NodeJS example on how to do so:

```
/**
 * HTTP function that supports CORS requests.
 *
 * @param {Object} req Cloud Function request context.
 * @param {Object} res Cloud Function response context.
 */
exports.corsEnabledFunction = (req, res) => {
  // Set CORS headers for preflight requests
  // Allows GETs from any origin with the Content-Type header
  // and caches preflight response for 3600s

  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    res.status(204).send('');
  } else {
    res.send('Hello World!');
  }
};
```

You can also use an external library to handle CORS for you. For further information you can read the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests).